# Is the FH2 Wheel Spin feature only for Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, forza-horizon-2

Today, I learned that there was a Wheel Spin feature when leveling up that enables the chance to randomly win credits or cars.

However, I'm up to level 158 and I've yet to see this. Furthermore, I'm on Xbox 360 and all the Youtube videos that I see, are for Xbox One.

Is this Wheel Spin feature only for Xbox One? Furthermore, if I haven't spun yet, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this was an unmentioned [Version Difference](http://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postst23370_Why-am-i-not-getting-any-wheelspin-rewards-xbox-360.aspx). The 360 Version does not have this wheelspin feature. You can see all the other version differences [here](http://forzamotorsport.net/en-us/news/fh2_x360).

Comment: thanks for the links... FWIW, I really did google before posting here :/